# Laravel LocalStorage getItem returning null

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm having some trouble retrieving values from localStorage. I'm trying to get item from this :
[image]

My input :

```
<input type="text" name="kd_lokasi2" id="kd_lokasi_kasir"> 
<input type="text" name="kd_shift2" id="kd_shift_kasir">
```

My script :

```
document.getElementById("kd_lokasi_kasir").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("kd_lokasi");
document.getElementById("kd_shift_kasir").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("kd_shift");
```

And use `@kd_lokasi_kasir = '".$request->kd_lokasi2."'` and `@kd_shift = '".$request->kd_shift2."'` on my controller. It not working.

[image]

Comment: My input did not receive the value from local storage. When I tried to dd($request) the value is null. What do I do wrong with my retrieve localstorage data?

Comment: Oh i got it, you are right, that's should be .VALUE and not .innerHTML. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the value of an input, you need to use `.value` and not `.innerHTML`, like this:

```
document.getElementById("kd_lokasi_kasir").value = localStorage.getItem("kd_lokasi");
```